# Apache - Generate private key from an existing .crt file

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I have some apache instances running smoothly with a home-made generated certificate. Now I have to use a provided certificate, but what I had sent is only a .crt file. In tried to copy it into the proper directory, but when I try to restart the webserver, it logs:

```
SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

Which I think it's correct, because the .key file is the one I made myself. Is there any way to generate the proper .key file from the .crt?

Comment: The certificate is made out of your public key. The public and private keys are completely separate (by definition) and you can't generate one from the other. How was this new .crt file generated? There just *has* to be a key file and a CSR somewhere!

Comment: It's possible that the key is included with the file. What is the first line of the file? (Not the data, just the first text line which should hopefully give a hint on what type of file it is.)

Comment: @Alexios: I have no clue about how this file was generated :(
@JennyD: if I do a simple `cat` I see the following: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFCTCCA/` which I don't think it what you are referring to.

Comment: The topic makes no sense even if the private key is concated to the crt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your self signed certificate you probably did something like this:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
       -keyout mysitename.key -out mysitename.crt
```

And then created lines like this for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/website
ServerName www.domain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/primary.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

With a CA signed cert things change slightly. You need to use the `private.key` that was used to sign the CA cert, and not the file that you used to do the self signing cert.

In some cases you can export the key from the file that's given to you but we'd need to know more information about the actual certificate file that you were given.

#### Example

I've dealt with .p12 files where I've needed to extract the .key file from it.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in star_qmetricstech_com.p12 -out star_qmetricstech_com.key
```

But with SSL certificates there are many types of container files and so you have to pay special attention to the different files, and which ones were used together.

#### References

- [How to Create and Install an Apache Self Signed Certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html)